# autofill search box here maps restrict country to United Kingdom using here maps api

Tags: javascript, here-api

How to limit here map search box to restrict to Country to United Kingdom or to cities within UK only.

here is my code:-

nokia.Settings.set("app_id", "DemoAppId01082013GAL");
    nokia.Settings.set("app_code", "AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg");
    // Use staging environment (remove the line for production environment)
    nokia.Settings.set("serviceMode", "cit");

    var basicSearchBox = new nokia.places.widgets.SearchBox({
        targetNode: "basicSearchBox",

        searchCenter: function () {
            return {
                latitude: 51.50642,
                longitude: -0.12721
            };
        },
        onResults: function (data) {
            var result;
               var resultsElt = document.getElementById("basicSearchBox");


            for (var i = 0, len = data.results.items.length; i

Answer (score 1):

JS API 2.x is phased out, it is highly recommended to migrate to 3.x

In equivalent search box does not have a Country filter
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/servicesPlaces/search-for-places

Maybe you can use Geocoder which does support country filter
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/servicesRouting/geocode-a-location-from-address

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-geocode.html